# scale_x_date for each facet in facet_grid ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I scale the x-axis for each facet grid? I attempted `scales = "free"` but for some reason this does not work for density or histogram. Here is what I've attempted.

The graph shows all of the dates from `date` instead of just the x-values for that facet-grid.

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(paste(sample(2000:2010, size = 100, replace = TRUE) - 1, "01", "01", sep = "-")), 
                 fact = sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = TRUE))

df <- df %>% mutate(year = format(as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, fill = factor(fact))) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.3, bins = 50) + 
  facet_grid(year ~ ., scales = "free", space="free") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: What would you like it to look like?

Answer (score 2):

Huh. That seems really weird to me. You can use `facet_wrap` and make it look more like `facet_grid`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, fill = factor(fact))) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.3, binwidth = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~year, scales = "free", ncol = 1,
             strip.position = "right") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Or you can switch to a horizontal layout.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, fill = factor(fact))) + 
geom_histogram(alpha = 0.3, binwidth = 1) + 
facet_grid(~year, scales = "free") + 
theme_bw() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

But... I don't know why `scales = "free"` isn't working.

Comment: Yea, it seems like the formula in `facet_grid()` is the thing that is throwing it off. Certain formulas work and others don't